# Is there a way to atomically flush a binary semaphore in C++ on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, semaphore, condition-variable

Some kernels provide a "[flush](http://www.embeddedlinux.org.cn/rtconforembsys/5107final/LiB0038.html#wbp08Chapter6T3P3)" operation on semaphore to unblock all tasks waiting on a semaphore.

For example, VxWorks has a [semFlush()](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~courses/ee8205/Data-Sheets/Tornado-VxWorks/vxworks/ref/semLib.html#semFlush) API that atomically unblocks all tasks pended on a specified semaphore, i.e., all tasks will be unblocked before any is allowed to run.

I am implementing a C++ class on Linux that behaves like a Binary Semaphore and also has this "flush" functionality. Unfortunately, [semaphore.h](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/semaphore.h.html) on Linux doesn't provide flush() or broadcast() like APIs.

**What I have tried: Using [condition variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to implement binary semaphore**.
Here's my pseudo code:

```
class BinarySem
{
    BinarySem();

    bool given;
    mutex m;
    condition_var cv;
    give();
    take();
    take( Timeout T );
    tryTake();
    flush();
}

BinarySem::BinarySem()
: given(false)
{}

// take(Timeout T), tryTake() not shown
// to make question concise on StackOverflow

BinarySem::give()
{
    {
        lock_guard lk(m);
        given = true;
    }
    cv.notify_one();
}   

BinarySem::flush()
{
    {
        lock_guard lk(m);
        given = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
}

BinarySem::take()
{
    unique_lock lk(m);
    while(!given)
    {
        cv.wait(lk);
    }
    given = false;
    lk.unlock();
}
```

However, this `flush()` won't behave in the correct way.
Say, we have 2 threads waiting on a BinarySem (i.e. they both have called `take()`).
Let these threads be `hiPrioThread` and `loPrioThread`.

When `flush()` is called on the `BinarySem` object, the `hiPrioThread` would exit from `take()` and run.
When it yields (`hiPrioThread` just yields, it has not yet exited), the `loPrioThread` would still not be able to run because boolean `given` is now `false` again. The boolean is required as a protection against spurious wake-ups.

On the contrary, a semaphore's `flush()` function should just unblock all threads and they can run whenever they get a chance.

What if I don't set `given = false` at the end of `take()`? That will make my code vulnerable to spurious wake-ups and then multiple threads might get unblocked when `give()` is used.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: `semaphore.h` is archaic sysv interface. A condition variable, and notify_all, matches what's described here as a "semaphore". notify_all should be sufficient for this. Also note that notify_all should be invoked while still holding the associated mutex lock, unless one manages their sequencing ***very*** carefully. If notify_all doesn't work for some reason, you need to show a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, instead of pseudocode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Borrow a concept from some "CyclicBarrier" implementations and have a generation or cycle counter.

"Flushing" the semaphore is then advancing the generation.  Each taker makes note of its generation before it waits, and the taker waits for the semaphore to be `given` *or* for the generation to change:

```
BinarySem::flush() {
  {
    lock_guard lk(m);
    current_gen++;    // "flush" all waiters from the previous gen
    //given = true;   // No need to give; the 'current' taker will do this when done
  }
  cv.notify_all();
}

BinarySem::take() {
  lock_guard lk(m);
  uint64_t my_generation = current_gen;
  while (!given && my_generation == current_gen) {
    cv.wait(lk);
  }
  if (my_generation == current_gen) {
    given = false;
  }
}
```

(Warning: untested)

Comment: The `flush()` function should **not** do `given = true`. Only `give()` must set `given = true` because `flush()` should only affect threads waiting on it and not affect any threads that call `take()` after `flush()` is called.

Comment: @AyushSinha are you suggesting that the "current" taker would then call give and make the semaphore useful again?  That seems reasonable

Comment: Either the current taker or any other thread could call give(). I would give that responsibility/option to the developer.

Comment: Fair enough.  Edited